# Gradle/NDK/CMake: Build .aar that "dynamically" includes other external .aar installed by end-user

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm creating a library that uses JNI to interop with some C++ code. My C++ code tries to include another library's C++ code, which the end-user has installed separately (not through maven repository, but as an `.aar`).

In my C++ code I try to include the other library like this:

```
#include <hermes/hermes.h>
```

But obviously I cannot build my library into a `.aar` because `<hermes/hermes.h>` (and it's implementation) cannot be found. I don't want to manually include the Hermes library in my library, since it's pretty huge. Also the user then can't update the Hermes library.

So the folder hierarchy on the end-user's machine looks like this:

```
app/
└── node_modules/
    ├── my-jni-library
    │   └── my-jni-library.aar
    └── hermes-engine/
        ├── include/
        ├── hermes-debug.aar
        └── hermes-release.aar
```

1. I am trying to include `hermes-engine/include` in `my-jni-library.aar`'s C++ code.
2. I am trying to "dynamically" link whatever version of `hermes-debug.aar`/`hermes-release.aar` the user has installed against my `my-jni-library.aar`.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this entirely from your side. You would need to depend on the hermes AAR and the user would need to configure gradle to get that from their local AAR rather than from maven by following https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html

Comment: How would I "depend on the Hermes AAR"? It is packaged locally, not through maven. I can import it's public headers (add to include_directories in CMake), but I can't package my .aar without linking the sources (which I don't have)

Comment: `implementation(project(":hermes-engine"))` if AGP is doing the building, but based on the directory structure this is npm, so I have no idea. It may not be possible.